# npm install not installing dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

Running npm init creates only package.json. No node_modules. 
Running npm install  then shows installed, but there's no node_modules created, and no module installed.
When I run my code it shows Module not found.

I tried other solutions, from all over the internet, but none solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

`npm init` just creates an "empty" `package.json` with the information you provided during the setup. Running `npm install` directly after a `npm init` will find no decendencies to install. If you have code like `import _ from "lodash"` or similar you also need to do `npm install lodash --save` to install that specific library (which will also add it to your `package.json` file).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `npm install` to install modules used in your current project, not `npm init`. `rm -rf` your current `node_modules` folder, then try `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your nodejs is not installed properly. You can install the nodejs again and use nvm to  manage the nodejs version.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and here is a solution that worked for me:

Give it a try and follow these instructions:

× create package.json -> 'npm init'

× check node version -> 'node -v'

× add this version to package.json as a dependency

example:

```
"dependencies": {   
   "node": "^v16.9.1"
}
```

× (don't forget to put the comma before and/or after dependencies)

× run 'npm i'

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29848216)